# In my Cell Phone,it occurs "@@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree"

Tags: java, android, fatal-error, libc, abort

> 04-07 10:45:29.340: A/libc(18699): @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS
>   IN dlfree 04-07 10:45:29.340: A/libc(18699): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
>   at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)

The above is all the log.In the project,it doesn't use `JNI` and `AsyncTask`.
There is no more log for this problem,so i don't know why and can't solve it.

Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: You may not use JNI, but the Android framework does all over the place.  The DEADBAAD address means that someone made a call that eventually hit C code that passed in an invalid address.

Comment: I used cache ThreadPool ,Lrucache and achartengine in my project.In the place i use achartengine the problem occurs more,I create a runnable into ThreadPool and use handler post a runnable to paint achartengine view

Comment: @GabeSechan,see the above,please help me.my experience is poor ，i may not find the problem where it is.